# Visual Studio 2008 SP1 assembly reference confusion

Tags: visual-studio-2008, version, gac, .net-assembly, sql-server-ce-3.5

I am using Visual Studio 2008 SP1 on Windows XP SP3 to develop some .NET Compact Framework 3.5 SP1 solution for Windows CE 6.

I want to use SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 in my solution, however I notice something very strange with how Visual Studio treats assembly references.

I have installed both "SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 for Windows *Desktop*" (SSCERuntime_x86-ENU.msi) and "SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 for Windows *Mobile*" (SSCEDeviceRuntime-ENU.msi). The former puts *two* versions of the System.Data.SqlServerCE assembly and one version of the System.Data.SqlServerCe.Entity assembly into Windows XP's GAC, while the latter does not seem to put any assembly into Windows XP's GAC. Here already, it looks strange because GAC reports the versions of the two assemblies to be 3.5.1.0 and 3.5.0.0 for System.Data.SqlServerCE, and 3.5.1.0 for System.Data.SqlServerCE.Entity, whereas in the installation directories of SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 ("C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v3.5" and "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v3.5\Desktop"), Windows Explorer reports both assemblies to be version 3.5.8080.0. Now I know that 3.5.0.0 is supposed to be for *vanilla* SQL Server Compact 3.5 (i.e. *no SP*) and 3.5.1.0 is supposed to be for *SP1*, not SP2. I did not install either vanilla or SP1, so why are they even there?

Furthermore, in Visual Studio 2008 SP1, when I try to add the System.Data.SqlServerCE assembly from the "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v3.5\*Devices*" directory, Visual Studio 2008 SP1 reports a version number of 3.5.1.0 in the Properties panel. This version number seems to be retrieved from the GAC'ed assembly, which shouldn't even be for .NET **Compact Framework**. The real version number in "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v3.5\*Devices*" is supposed to be 3.5.8080.0, again.

I know that it is possible to use private deployment, as described at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg213826.aspx, but I'm still bothered by the fact that Visual Studio seems to be referencing the wrong platform-version of the assembly altogether when I don't specifically resort to private deployment.

Maybe I just don't understand how Visual Studio works in conjunction with GAC. Can somebody enlighten me? Is there a way to "fix" this without resorting to private deployment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *File Version* is 3.5.8080.0.

The *Assembly Version* is 3.5.1.0.

You can confirm this by opening the properties of the file in Explorer, and switching to the "Version" tab (well, you can for the Desktop files which also report themselves as 3.5.8080.0, but are in fact 3.5.1.0. You can't for the Devices files, but the same explanation applies)

---

Visual Studio doesn't interact with the GAC at all when it comes to referencing assemblies (in fact, see the related question [Why does the .NET tab in the 'Add Reference' dialog in Visual Studio not list the contents of the GAC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871984/why-does-the-net-tab-in-the-add-reference-dialog-in-visual-studio-not-list-the))

Comment: I see. I have been wondering what is the difference between File Version and Assembly Version since I recently noticed that DLLs have two versions in the Version tab and they always had the same value for the few times I saw them (in other DLLs). I googled about the difference after you pointed out that the values are different. Now I understand the difference between the two properties. I also just found out that assemblies in the GAC don't have a *File Version*. Instead, they have a *Product Version*. For System.Data.SqlServerCE, it just happens to have the same value as *File Version*.