# Can I use System.Web.Mvc from a Class Library?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, class-library

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC application, but I'm trying to remove everything but Controller code from my project and put it in it's own Class Library.

I've got some code that is
`Using System.Web.Mvc;`

But it doesn't seem to be letting me access it.  I have Referenced the `System.Web` Namespace in the project.

> Bassically I'm getting errors on the iActionFilter and the FilterAttribute stuff.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Turns out that the `System.Web.MVC` Assembly is NOT installed in the GAC.  It has to be referenced from
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 2\Assemblies`

Comment: Oh yes, that's a good point. It actually is in the GAC, but something that trips a lot of people up is the fact that the ".NET" tab on the Add References window is actually *not* just an enumeration of the GAC. [See here for more details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495973/getting-assemblies-to-show-in-the-net-tab-of-add-reference)

Answer (score 7):

Web.Mvc was not in Extensions for me.  You can install if from nuget:

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc
```

Comment: That makes total sense...  To install System.Web.Mvc, install Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.  =)  Worked for me!

Comment: I once read somewhere, "Naming things is hard".  I agree with the author of that statement.  And also feel the pain when things aren't named as any sane person would expect.  =)

Answer (score 5):

you can go to :

Add Reference > Assemblies > Extentions and add system.web.mvc :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the MVC stuff is in the `System.Web.Mvc` assembly. There should be nothing wrong with referencing that from a class library.

Answer (score 0):

For MVC 4 it is installed to:

### `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4\Assemblies`

### Development Note:

I am always cautious about including non-GAC assemblies from a fixed drive location (which may vary between machines, or not be installed at all). Instead I would create a `~/ThirdParty/Microsoft/Microsoft ASP.NET/ASP.NET MVC 4/Assemblies` folder, in source control, and copy the assemblies there for all machine to reference.

Comment: agreed. This is an extremely old post... at this time, I check everything into source except System.* crap.