# Remove references from the .net tab of visual studio 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

How can I remove references from the .net tab of the add reference dialog of visual studio 2010?

Visual studio 2010 autopoints my references to the .net tab location when I browse to them and I want to be sure to remove them so my references don't get changed.

Comment: not sure what you're asking here.

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495973/getting-assemblies-to-show-in-the-net-tab-of-add-reference/496023#496023) may give you some suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're a bit confuzzled about what's happening here.  Yes, you use the Browse tab to add references to your assemblies.  Or the Projects tab if those projects are part of the solution.  But that does *not* add these assemblies to the .NET tab.  That one is filled from directories whose names are listed in a registry key.  Put there by an installer. You should never alter those keys yourself, that just causes misery whenever you switch machines.

You don't have to do anything.